# How test function call inside ngOnChanges in angular jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have a child component in angular app which calls function in `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook.

```
export class GameComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges { 

   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     this.generateRandomIcon();
   }

   generateRandomIcon(): void {
     //some code goes here...
   }
}
```

Now I am trying to develop unit test to check if `generateRandomIcon()` function is called.

Here is the tests:

```
describe('GameComponent', () => {
  let component: GameComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GameComponent>;
  let setGameItemImageSpy: any;
  let el: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [CommonModule],
      declarations: [GameComponent],
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GameComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        el = fixture.debugElement;
      });
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should check if generateRandomIcon was called in ngOnChanges lifecycle hook', () => {
    setGameItemImageSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(GameComponent, [
      'generateRandomIcon',
    ]);
    spyOn(component, 'ngOnChanges');

    setGameItemImageSpy.generateRandomIcon();
    expect(setGameItemImageSpy.generateRandomIcon).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(setGameItemImageSpy.generateRandomIcon).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

When unit tests is running then everything is ok, but anyway when I measure the coverage of tests then this part is **not covered**.

[image]

So, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you should explicitly call change detection. If you do - Angular will call your component hooks.

```
  it('should check if generateRandomIcon was called in ngOnChanges lifecycle hook', () => {
    const generateRandomIconSpy = spyOn(component, 'generateRandomIcon');
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(generateRandomIconSpy ).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this approach works only if I add '  component.ngOnChanges();' before 'fixture.detectChanges();' change detection.

Comment: I doesn't https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35614. Unfortunately, the Angular team seems to have a habit of closing issues rather than fixing them.